# About to Freeze the imageView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have Footer in my Layout and There are some EditText on the upper side of the footer. now while i am trying to write in to the Edit text default keypad is shown. and the footer is Also move from bottom to the upper side of the Default keypad. . . How can i fix it ?
The Layout code is as Follow. . .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- For the Header Part -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dip"
    android:background="@drawable/header_gradient">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/backToMainMenuFromDonationForm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/backhome"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <TextView 
        android:text="Donation Form"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="240dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dip"/>
</LinearLayout>    
<!-- Header Part Finish -->
```

```
</LinearLayout>
 <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow_small"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:layout_height="25dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
            android:layout_width="10dip">
        </ImageView>
```

Please Help me. . .
Thanks.

Comment: plz paste your code of manifest of only this activity..?

Comment: Here is the Manifest code for the activity of the above Layout. .   <activity android:name="com.menu.donationform.DonationForm">
        </activity>

Comment: see my answer n let me know it will be work or not?

Answer (score 0):

ok, add this code in activity of your menifest ..

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"   

android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

Comment: Its not working. . . Still my footer and the Other Layout goes on the default Keypad Layout. . . How to Fix it ??

Comment: Sorry Boss, it still not Working . . .

Comment: let me know in detail exactly what u want..?

Comment: My Footer is move on the upper side of the default keyboard while it is appear on the screen. I dont allow it to Move and Place as it is. .

Comment: this code is working for me... let me know what is in your footer..?n let me know detail abt your app..

Comment: In My Application i have put the ImageView as the Footer.

Comment: footer n header are in same xml.?